# Install a certificate authority into Xcode SwiftUI preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm attempting to load an `AsyncImage` from an enterprise HTTPS server that's signed by in-house certificate authority, but it of course fails because the SwiftUI preview environment doesn't trust that CA. How can I install and trust that in-house CA root certificate into the *SwiftUI preview* environment in Xcode?

I've already dropped the certificate into the Simulator, marked it as trusted, and ensured my app builds and does successfully load images there, but changes to the Simulator environment don't appear to affect the SwiftUI preview embedded in Xcode.

As well, the root certificate is also installed and trusted in the host Mac's keychain, and those changes also do not affect the SwiftUI preview.

(Filed with Apple as `FB10667327` in case this just isn't possible)